# How should be approach Windows 8 Store apps tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, windows-8

There are times where users have specific question about specific apps within Windows 8.  How should we tag these specific questions?

I propose we do the following:

1. Have a general [windows-8-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-store-app):  This deals with any/all apps that can be found withing the [windows-8-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-store)
2. Have specific tags for Microsoft developed apps that come shipped with Win8: [win8-mail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/win8-mail),[win8-calendar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/win8-calendar),[win8-people](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/win8-people),etc
3. Refrain from creating specifc tags for all other apps, as these are not as likely to be used as the main applications.

Comment: I don't think we need to change anything. We create new tags when necessary or considered useful.

Comment: I don't think fundamentally that we should treat windows 8 apps any differently from other software. We have a thunderbird tag, so win8-mail should have a tag and so on.

Comment: @journeymangeek what my main concern is the apps that are not as common.